# STL/boost way to indirectly call a method repeatly for each object inside a vector

Tags: c++, boost, stl

Suppose I have a vector of objects. For each element inside the vector, I want to invoke a function via a member. The code can be illustrated as below.

```
class CMyClass
{
public:
   void g();
};

class CAnotherClass
{
public:
   void f();
   CMyClass m_object;
};

std::vector<CAnotherClass> vec;
// This is easy. What about m_object->g()?
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::mem_fn(&CAnotherClass::f));
```

Calling `f()` on each object is as easy as shown above. What if I want to call `m_object->g()` on each object? Hopefully, I don't want change the interface of `CAnotherClass` to add a dummy function just to call `m_object->g()`.

Is there any STL/boost way to do it w/o writing the loop myself?

Comment: Actually I'll suggest to add a function for `m_object.g()`. Because in many cases `m_object` would be `private`. And, `m_object.g()` must mean something, so it deserves a function for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide a seperate function, like this one:

```
void call_g(CAnotherClass & c) { c.m_object.g(); }
```

Then pass that to `std::for_each`.

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), call_g);
```

If your compiler supports lambdas, a C++11 feature, things are better, because you can define the function at its point of use:

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](CAnotherClass & c) { c.m_object.g(); });
```

But if your compiler supports lambdas, maybe it supports range for loops, another C++11 feature.  In my opinion, range for loops make `std::for_each` obsolete.  It's much more succinct.

```
for (auto & c : vec) { c.m_object.g(); }
```

Comment: As for the obsolete for_each: yes and no. for_each on complete ranges can (and imo should) be replaced by ranged for, but there is no substitution for for_each on subranges, at least not within STL.

Comment: @ArneMertz: Not in the Standard Library, but there's always `boost::iterator_range`.  But personally, with the advent of `auto`, I find plain old for loops more palatable than either of those options.

Comment: if iterator_range is available, range based for is the best choice for me. `for (auto& c : make_iterator_range(it1, it2)) { c.foo(); }` just looks good imho. I never liked for-loops on iterators because of the need to always dereference the iterator inside the loop body, so I would prefer for_each with lambdas over traditional for on iterators.

Comment: I'll use a static member function in my case.

Comment: @EricZ: That's fine, if you want to do that.  But it smells like bad design to me. I believe you had the right idea when you said "I don't want change the interface of CAnotherClass to add a dummy function just to call m_object->g()". I don't see why you should modify the class just so you can use it in this particular way. If you can't use the C++11 options, I would just create the first function (perhaps with a more well thought out name), defined in the same file where the call to `for_each` happens. But, whatever floats your boat.

Comment: @Benjamin, The static function is in the same class where `for_each` is called.